# Kubectl exec .. -- /bin/bash doesn't connect

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

recently I've been unable to connect to the bash on my kubernetes cluster. And I'm at a loss as to why. Have anyone else experienced this?

**What happened**:
I can no longer connect to /bin/bash in my running pods. It simply hangs when trying to exec the command. I've verified that bash is installed (`/bin/bash --version`).
I've tried both locally and from the google cloud console

**What you expected to happen**:
That my local terminal successfully connects to the pods bash terminal

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)**:
I've only tested it on my cluster, but the command I'm running is:

`kubectl exec -i POD_ID --namespace=NAMESPACE -c CONTAINER -- /bin/bash`

I've also run it with DEBUG=1 which results in the following:

```
DEBUG=1 kubectl exec -i POD_ID --namespace=NAMESPACE -c CONTAINER -- 
/bin/bash
I0412 10:52:14.560443    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc420242140) Create stream
I0412 10:52:14.560486    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc420242140) Stream added, broadcasting: 1
I0412 10:52:14.611561    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) Reply frame 
received for 1
I0412 10:52:14.611658    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc4203e26e0) Create stream
I0412 10:52:14.611692    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc4203e26e0) Stream added, broadcasting: 3
I0412 10:52:14.656684    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) Reply frame 
received for 3
I0412 10:52:14.656725    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc4202425a0) Create stream
I0412 10:52:14.656737    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc4202425a0) Stream added, broadcasting: 5
I0412 10:52:14.702100    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) Reply frame 
received for 5
I0412 10:52:14.702140    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc420659680) Create stream
I0412 10:52:14.702151    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) 
(0xc420659680) Stream added, broadcasting: 7
I0412 10:52:14.746707    2675 logs.go:41] (0xc4200aed10) Reply frame 
received for 7
```

**Anything else we need to know?**:

**Environment**:
- Kubernetes version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", 
GitVersion:"v1.8.6", 
GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538b34a9ceb3e406689c", 
GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:34:11Z", 
GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9+", 
GitVersion:"v1.9.6-gke.0", 
GitCommit:"cb151369f60073317da686a6ce7de36abe2bda8d", 
GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-21T19:01:20Z", 
GoVersion:"go1.9.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

- Cloud provider or hardware configuration:
  `Google Cloud`
- OS (e.g. from `/etc/os-release`):

  PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
  NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
  VERSION_ID="9"
  VERSION="9 (stretch)"
  ID=debian
  HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
  SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
  BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
- Kernel (e.g. `uname -a`):
  `Linux bounce-deployment-f95687cbc-mfgtg 4.4.111+ #1 SMP Thu Feb 1 22:06:37 PST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Install tools:
- Others:

Comment: Can you try a new GKE cluster and see you can connect there. This might be just that your router/ISP/firewall is preventing you from using Websockets protocol etc.

Comment: As in create a new cluster?

But if that was the case, shouldn't it work when I use the google cloud console?

I can connect to a bash when I provide it with the -i argument. But it isn't connecting to any of the running jobs

Comment: Do you mean Cloud Shell also doesn’t work? Does non-bash programs work (like “date”)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to pass `-t` to `kubectl exec` command, just like `docker exec -i -t <container_name> bash`.

From the help command:

> -t, --tty=false: Stdin is a TTY

Comment: Thank you! That did it! I have no idea why it worked previously without it, but you just saved me from a major headache.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been that $DEBUG is conflicting with the k8s's internal debugging flag. Try rename or remove $DEBUG environment variable.

I ran into a similar issue - when you set environment variable DEBUG to truthy values, the kubernetes container went nuts with all sorts of logs.go print out all over the screen with every single key stroke (just like what you saw there in the log).

I disabled the environment variable DEBUG by setting it to `0` or `false`, it went back to normal. kubectl exec works with a normal shell prompt.